# Remove space between header and title of listoffigures and listoftables

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, chapters

Stuck with my last problem:

At the end of my document, I'm adding `listoffigures` and `listoftables`. As I both want them to be on a new page, I've realized that these are not behave like other chapters and the defined `\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=-.2cm, afterindent=false]{chapter}`  does not work... These 2 take too much vspace after the header... Why is this?

Could someone help me to achieve this for `listoffigures` and `listoftables` as well?

source (tried to remove the unnecessary stuff):

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%           Präambel                %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass{scrreprt}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%       Packages        %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[bmargin=1.5cm,tmargin=1.5cm, headheight=1cm, includehead, includefoot]{geometry} %Seitenränder definieren
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman, english]{babel}
\usepackage[toc]{glossaries}
\usepackage{float} %Unterdrückt das Fliessen eines Bildes wenn statt "h" "H" als float angegeben wird.
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[square,sort&compress,comma,numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage[manualmark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage[colorlinks, urlcolor=blue, linkcolor=black, citecolor=black]{hyperref}
\usepackage[german, noabbrev, nameinlink]{cleveref} %Automatische Verweise mit \cref{} oder \cpageref{} auf \label{}. Bei englischer Arbeit muss "german" durch "english" ersetzt werden.

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%   Konfigurationen     %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%Kopfzeile und Fusszeile
\ihead*{\raisebox{-0.1\height}[0pt][0pt]{\includegraphics{example-image}}}
\cfoot*{\pagemark}

%Kapitel-Abstand zu Kopfzeile verkleinern
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=-.2cm, afterindent=false]{chapter}

%Inhaltsverzeichnis
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{\subsubsectionnumdepth}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{\subsubsectiontocdepth}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[linefill=\TOCLineLeaderFill]{tocline}{chapter}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[pagenumberformat=\sffamily]{tocline}{section,subsection}

%Bibliografie-Stil
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}

%Glossar
\makeglossaries
\renewcommand*\glspostdescription{\dotfill}

%Quellcode
\renewcommand\lstlistingname{Quellcode}
\renewcommand\lstlistlistingname{Quellcodes}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%           Dokument                %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{ngerman}



\pagenumbering{arabic}\setcounter{page}{2} %Seitennummerierung ab hier



\tableofcontents{}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%       Kapitel         %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%       Verweise        %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abbildungsverzeichnis}
\clearpage
\listoffigures
\clearpage
\listoftables
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Tabellenverzeichnis}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Quellcodes}
\lstlistoflistings

%Anhänge
\input{Kapitel/Anhang}

\end{document}
```

Examples:
[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't use the KOMA classes but in the regular `book` and `report` classes the titles og the LoF and Lot are set using `\chapter*{...}`.

Comment: @PeterWilson With `scrreprt` and `scrbook` the titles of LoF and LoT are set as unnumbered chapters, too. But package `tocloft` changes the formatting of these titles ...

Comment: Either remove package `tocloft` or load it with option `titles`. Off topic: the page number of the LoF and the "Quellcodes" will be wrong in ToC. If the LoT is longer than one page, its page number will be also wrong in ToC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your MWE but as you had not supplied the `Kapitel/Anhang` file I could not generate what you showed.

I was not prepared to try and guess what you had in that file. --- GOM

I noticed that you used the `tocloft` package which does not always work well in conjunction with `scrreprt` but in this case it does. Put

```
\setlength{\cftbeforeloftitleskip}{0pt}
```

before `\listoffigures`, and

```
\setlength{\cftbeforelottitleskip}{0pt}
```

before `\listoftables`, changing `0pt` to suit, which will reduce the space before the LoF and LoT titles.

Answer (score 1):

Package `tocloft` changes the formatting of the list titles. To avoid these changes you have to set the package option `titles`: `\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}`.

But it is not recommended to load package `tocloft` if a KOMA-Script class is used! As far as I can see, you do not use macros of package `tocloft`, but loading the package already changes the formatting of the lists titles.

So you should remove package `tocloft` and additionally all the `\clearpage` before or after the lists. (Additional remark: the manual entries will result in wrong page numbers in ToC for lists longer than one page). Use the class option `listof=totoc` to get ToC entries for the lists.

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[
  listof=totoc% ToC entry for LoF and LoT
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{scrhack}% added: provides patches for packages float and listings, see package documentation

\usepackage[vmargin=1.5cm, headheight=1cm, includeheadfoot]{geometry} %Seitenränder definieren
\ifluatex
  \usepackage{fontspec}% used with lualatex
\else
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% used with pdflatex
\fi
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english,main=ngerman]{babel}% set main=ngerman, then the switch at the begin of the document can be removed

\usepackage{pdfpages}% loads package graphicx
%\usepackage{graphicx}% already loaded by pdfpages!

\usepackage{listings}% do not load this package twice

\usepackage[manualmark]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\usepackage[colorlinks, urlcolor=blue, linkcolor=black, citecolor=black]{hyperref}
\usepackage[german, noabbrev, nameinlink]{cleveref} %Automatische Verweise mit \cref{} oder \cpageref{} auf \label{}. Bei englischer Arbeit muss "german" durch "english" ersetzt werden.


\ihead*{\raisebox{-0.1\height}[0pt][0pt]{\includegraphics[height=\baselineskip]{example-image}}}
\cfoot*{\pagemark}

\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=-.2cm, afterindent=false]{chapter}

% ToC
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{\subsubsectionnumdepth}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{\subsubsectiontocdepth}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[linefill=\TOCLineLeaderFill]{tocline}{chapter}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[pagenumberformat=\sffamily]{tocline}{section,subsection}



% Listings
\providecaptionname{ngerman}{\lstlistingname}{Quellcode}
\providecaptionname{ngerman}{\lstlistlistingname}{Quellcodes}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
\centering
\Huge Titelpage
\end{titlepage}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\lstlistoflistings

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Additional remarks:

Load package `scrhack` if you use package `float` and/or `listings`.

Do not load package `listings` twice.

Package `pdfpages` already loads package `graphicx`. So there is no need to load it again.

Package `lipsum` is only for dummy text and not needed for your document.